# Does SyncAdapter is really required to Add a Quick Contact badge?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-contacts

I would like my application to appear in the quick contact badge.
I used SyncAdapter (as described in [this](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1) great tutorial).

But since I would like this badge to be visible in all my contacts and just open my app, it seems that creating my own account and contacts for each existing contact and keep this account updated, is a very clumsy way to do so.

Is there another way to do it?

[image: QuickContact badge]

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.

The key is using the right mime type.
To make my app visible in the quick contact badge for all contacts I used the following settings in my manifest file:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and that's it - no sync provider or any additional services or activities.

I would be grateful if anyone knows how to make the application badge available only to contacts with phone number, instead for all contacts.